# Confidence Interval, uniform distribution

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, inference

> Let $X_1,...X_n$ random sample from
>   $f(x;\theta)=I_{[\theta-\frac{1}{2};\theta+\frac{1}{2}]}(x)$.
>   i) Show that
>   $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is a confidence interval for $\theta$.ii) find
>   your confidence level.

The first item I do not know how to show that a range is confidence interval.

In the second item I tried $$P(X_{(1)}\leq \theta \leq X_{(n)})=P(X_{(n)}\geq\theta)-P(X_{(1)}\leq \theta)$$.

But the solutions say that $P(X_{(1)}\leq \theta \leq X_{(n)})=P(X_{(n)}\geq\theta)-P(X_{(1)}\geq \theta)$

But I don't understand this inequality,where $X_{(n)}$ is the max and $X_{(1)}$ is the minimum

Comment: Related discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/530709/find-a-confidence-interval-for-data-from-a-uniform-distribution-on-theta-5/530851#530851)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have you been provided with a definition of "*confidence interval*"? You generally answer such questions by reference to a definition (does the thing you're given satisfy the definition?).
2. The second can be easily seen by drawing a picture. Loosely speaking, the region between (green) is the region to the left of $X_{(n)}$ (blue) minus the  region to the left of $X_{(1)}$ (red). So the set of cases where the region between the two encompasses the parameter is the set of cases where the parameter is left of $X_{(n)}$ minus those cases where it's also left of $X_{(1)}$.

[image]

Comment: But the cases where $X_{(1)}$ is left don't means $P(X_{(1)}<\theta)$?

Comment: I think now I understand it, is $P(X_{(1)}>\theta)$ because if $X_{(1)}>\theta$ this means that $\theta$ is out of the confidence interval, right?

Comment: Clearly, yes, in that case the CI would not include $\theta$.