# Confidence interval and probability

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, estimation, inference

Suppose that $T_1$ is $100\gamma$ percent lower confidence limit for $\tau(\theta)$ and $T_2$ is $100\gamma$ percent uper confidence limit for $\tau(\theta)$. Further assume that $P_\theta(T_1<T_2)=1$. Find a $100(2\gamma-1)$ percent confidence interval for $\tau(\theta)$.(Assume $\gamma>\frac{1}{2})$

Using the same I idead from here [Confidence Interval, uniform distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152659/confidence-interval-uniform-distribution).
$$P(T_1\leq\tau(\theta)\leq T_2)=P(T_2\geq\tau(\theta))-P(T_1\geq\tau(\theta))$$
$$=P(T_2\geq\tau(\theta))-[1-P(T_1\leq\tau(\theta))]=\gamma-1+\gamma=2\gamma-1$$

Because by definition from Mood, in one sided interval  $P(T_2\geq\tau(\theta))=\gamma$ and $P(T_1\leq\tau(\theta))=\gamma$.

But $P(T_1\leq\tau(\theta)\leq T_2)$ don't need to be $P(T_1\leq\tau(\theta)\leq T_2)=\gamma$?

And as I build the interval with such information?

Maybe I'm wrong understanding, but $(T_1,T_2)$ it would not be a confidence interval with confidence level $2\gamma-1$, assume that $\gamma>\frac{1}{2}$? Or I need to find $T_1,T_2$?

Comment: Also, do not model your reasoning after what is said in that link. They consider order statistics (max and min of the sample), which is completely different than what you have here.

Comment: If $[T_1,\infty]$ and $[-\infty,T_2]$ are both $100\gamma$%-CI for $\tau(\theta)$ *obtained from the same sample*, then it is indeed the case that $P(\tau(\theta) \in [T_1,T_2]) = 2\gamma-1$. If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are obtained from different samples, then the question does not provide sufficient information to calculate the probability $P(\tau(\theta) \in [T_1,T_2])$.